# jQuery get request not retrieving HTML

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to use a `$.get()` request to retrieve some HTML data which is returned inside a PHP file.

The jQuery:

```
$.get( "/invite/all", function( return_data ) {

   console.log(return_data);

});
```

The PHP:

```
public function getInvites()
{
        $invites = DB::table('invites')->where('user_to', '=', 2)->get();

        if(!empty($invites)) {

            ob_start();

            foreach ($invites as $invite):

                $invite_channel = DB::table('channels')->where('channel_id', '=', $invite->channel)->first();
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $invite_channel->channel_name; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <button>Action</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php

            endforeach;

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'empty' => false,
                'message' => ob_get_clean()
            ]);

        } else {

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'empty' => true,
                'message' => 'You currently have no invites'
            ]);

        }

}
```

When using Postman it returns the data as expected, but when I'm using this on a webpage, it shows the JSON but the `message` field is empty.

Comment: are you using get in postman? have you tried the url directly on the browser since it is a get?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I am using GET in postman, and yes I have tried the url directly in the browser which gives me the expected output

Comment: use the second parameter in your `$.get` function and check the http status.  Like this `function (return_data, status)` and do console.log for both

Comment: @NevilleNazerane As expected, `status` returns `success`

Comment: `$.get()`is a shorthand method for `$.ajax()`. Try using the latter to give yourself more control, eg with the option `dataType:'json'`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunatelly it still gives the same output. JSON with an empty `message`

Comment: Mysterious! Try changing property name from "message" to something else.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 It is isn't it! And still no luck :(

Comment: What happens if you hard-code a string in place of `ob_get_clean()`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 That does show up

Comment: I was trying to make sure the "/invite/all" maps to the right path. If you used the browser and postman, you would be giving the full path. If you didn't get the response in jquery when using "/invite/all", might be a 404

Comment: It wd appear that `ob_get_clean()` returns something that doesn't json encode properly. Could be as simple as a string containing an apostrophe.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Hmm thats interesting, I’ve also tried an `echo` of just the `ob_get_clean()` which just outputs nothing

Comment: What should it return?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 At least some HTML. So I’m guessing that it’s something with the `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: It's looking to be that way.

Comment: Maybe your approach using `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` isn't a good solution. Try to to add your HTML code as string to the response object instead of directly writing HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clean that up by moving the html to a blade template. Also if you used eloquent relationships that could get cleaned up a lil bit easier as well.

How stuff is displayed shouldn't be a concern of the controller in reality. We have the entire View layer for handling that. It just need to handle the request and return some type of response. Let the view layer handle the specifics of the markup.

```
public function getInvites()
{
    $invites = Invite::with('channel')->where('user_to', 2)->get();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'true',
        'empty' => $invites->isEmpty(),
        'message' => $invites->isEmpty()
            ? 'You currently have no invites'
            : view('partial.invites', ['invites' => $invites])->render(),
    ]);

}

// resources/views/partial/invites.blade.php

@foreach ($invites as $invite)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $invite->channel->channel_name }}</td>
    <td>
        <button>Action</button>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ob_start() and ob_get_clean(). Save your HTML Code in a variable and then add it to the response.

```
$html = '';
foreach ($invites as $invite) {
  $html += '<tr>';
  $html += '<td>' . $invite_channel->channel_name . '</td>';
  $html += '<td>';
  $html += '<button>Action</button>';
  $html += '</td>';
  $html += '</tr>';
}

return response()->json([
  'success' => true,
  'empty' => false,
  'message' => $html
]);
```

Comment: FWIW, php's example for `ob_get_clean()` uses `echo` to send stuff to the ob.